# Crontab: variables in the date/time fields

Tags: cron

When to run my scripts that go run reports can vary within the month as the data is not available at a standard time; sometimes on the 8th, sometimes on the 10th, etc.

I have many reports to execute so it would be fantastic to use the `cron` file like so:

```
##### VARIABLES #####
    DAY_TO_RUN=8

##### Monthly #####
    ## COGS REPORT
        0 12 $DAY_TO_RUN * * cd "/home/skilbjo/app/aqtl/jobs/Costs" ; node cogs_model.js >/dev/null
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you run it every minute with a test to determine whether the data is available? Isn't there a reliable way to tell?

Comment: Not really a good way to tell. The reports run for the past month's activity, but the DBAs load the tables every day. However quite frequently the loads fail (so incompletely monthly data), and it varies from month-to-month when the prior month's data is complete. So I was thinking; set the `day` as a variable, and when I get notification (manually, from an email from the DBAs) that the past month's data is completely loaded, then kick off the scripts to run the reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cron` by its nature do not yield to variable timing. What you want is a 3rd party job scheduler. A well known paid one is called "maestro" from the company formerly known as Tivoli (now IBM I think). Many open source equivalents exist just use google and the keywords.

Once you are in the job scheduler software land, you can make your data file a dependency to run a job. When your job's time to start, comes and passes, it looks for the dependency to be satisfied to start execution.

You can implement this similar function using a few simple shell scripts, depending on the nature of the job you want to run and how much time you want to invest in such an endeavor. After all, it is not rocket science material.